# oracle apex get a selected value of a select list via javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a select list on my page and I created a dynamic action on the list to execute some javascript based on selected value. I tried using

```
var sel_val = apex.item("P2_TYPES").getValue();
```

but it did not return the selected value

also tried using `$x('P2_TYPES')` but still unsuccessful - returns `false`

How can I retrieve a selected value of a select list from a dynamic action?

Comment: The code is correct. apex.item('ITEM_NAME').getValue() returns the selected value from a select list. If you create a dynamic action when this item change, so that code will get the value selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only with this information I can't say why this is not working, but the code is correct.

This will works.

Create a dynamic action

WHEN: change a item.
no condition

True action: execute javascript code

```
alert(apex.item("ITEM_NAME_HERE").getValue())
```

Comment: it was my bad - typo in the name